# Bash shell for data cleansing

Tags: bash, shell

I'm new to bash scripting and I am learning scripting for data cleansing. I have a large file which I have managed to cut out the necessary columns and save it to a new file. Need help to achieve the outcome I am looking for.

```
   2 Media Server Community - WebRTC, MP4, HLS, RTMP"
  29 Media Server Enterprise
   7 Media Server lite
  10 Media server lite 1.0
 468 Media server lite 2.0
   8 Media server lite 2.3
   1 Media server lite 2.4
  40 Media server lite 3.0
   3 Media server lite 3.3
```

How could I edit this file to now make the csv file as

```
   2 | Media Server Community - WebRTC, MP4, HLS, RTMP"
  29 | Media Server Enterprise
   7 | Media Server lite
  10 | Media server lite 1.0
 468 | Media server lite 2.0
   8 | Media server lite 2.3
   1 | Media server lite 2.4
  40 | Media server lite 3.0
   3 | Media server lite 3.3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd rather see you post (parts of) the original data file and show you how it's done all the way with awk, but here's what you asked for using GNU awk (`gensub`):

```
$ gawk '{print gensub(/([0-9]+ )/,"\\1| ",1,$0)}' file
```

Output:

```
   2 | Media Server Community - WebRTC, MP4, HLS, RTMP"
  29 | Media Server Enterprise
   7 | Media Server lite
...
```

**Edit:** Hmm, too much `gensub` lately I guess, just use awk:

```
$ awk '{sub(/([0-9]+ )/,"&| ")}1' file
```

Comment: I'm digging your `sub` answer. Yep,, too much `gensub` lately.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach with any `awk` is to use `match()` to locate where the first number and whitespace ends and then use `substr()` to print up to that point, add a `"|"` and then use `substr()` again to print from that point to the end, e.g.

```
awk '{ 
    match($0,/^[ \t0-9]+/)
    print substr($0,0,RLENGTH-1), "|", substr($0, RLENGTH+1)
}'
```

**Example Use/Output**

With your sample input in the file name `media`, you would do:

```
$ awk '{ match($0,/^[ \t0-9]+/); print substr($0,0,RLENGTH-1), "|", substr($0, RLENGTH+1) }' media
   2 | Media Server Community - WebRTC, MP4, HLS, RTMP"
  29 | Media Server Enterprise
   7 | Media Server lite
  10 | Media server lite 1.0
 468 | Media server lite 2.0
   8 | Media server lite 2.3
   1 | Media server lite 2.4
  40 | Media server lite 3.0
```

Answer (score 0):

All [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) / [zsh](/questions/tagged/zsh) answer.

If you are not married to the whitespace around the first field you can do:

```
$ while read -r x rest; do printf "%s|%s\n" "$x" "$rest"; done <file
2|Media Server Community - WebRTC, MP4, HLS, RTMP"
29|Media Server Enterprise
7|Media Server lite
10|Media server lite 1.0
468|Media server lite 2.0
8|Media server lite 2.3
1|Media server lite 2.4
40|Media server lite 3.0
3|Media server lite 3.3
```

That result is a single character `"|"` delimiter CSV file rather than having a three character `" | "` for a CSV delimiter (which is more difficult to deal with later...)

If you want the first field to be wider and a column, you can use a Bash regex to separate the first field from the rest:

```
while IFS= read -r line || [[ -n $line ]]; do 
    if [[ $line =~ ^[[:blank:]]*([[:digit:]]+)[[:blank:]]+(.*) ]]; then
        printf "%4s | %s\n" "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}" "${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
    fi  
done <file 
   2 | Media Server Community - WebRTC, MP4, HLS, RTMP"
  29 | Media Server Enterprise
   7 | Media Server lite
  10 | Media server lite 1.0
 468 | Media server lite 2.0
   8 | Media server lite 2.3
   1 | Media server lite 2.4
  40 | Media server lite 3.0
   3 | Media server lite 3.3
```

---

For an [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) answer, I would do:

```
awk -v de=" | " '
FNR==NR{length($1)>max ? max=length($1) : max=max; next}
{
    s=""
    for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) s=s ? s OFS $i : $i
    printf " %*s%s%s\n", max, $1, de, s
}
' file file
   2 | Media Server Community - WebRTC, MP4, HLS, RTMP"
  29 | Media Server Enterprise
   7 | Media Server lite
  10 | Media server lite 1.0
 468 | Media server lite 2.0
   8 | Media server lite 2.3
   1 | Media server lite 2.4
  40 | Media server lite 3.0
   3 | Media server lite 3.3
```

Answer (score 0):

With `sed`(1)

```
sed 's/^\([[:space:]]*[[:digit:]]\{1,\}\)/\1 |/' file.txt
```

---

- The `^` is an anchor which means the start/beginning.
- The `( )` is a capture group, (the `(` and `)` needs to be escaped with B.R.E.) what ever pattern is inside it will be in `\1`. Which is the first capture group.
- `[[:space:]]` white space.
- `*` is a quantifier that means zero or more.
- `[[:digit:]]` is an int.
- `{1,}` is a quantifier that means one or more, but the `{` and `}` needs to be escape with B.R.E. which is the default regex engine by `sed`.

---

If the `-E` flag/option (E.R.E.) is used the escaping can be omitted in the pattern matching.

```
sed -E 's/^([[:space:]]*[[:digit:]]{1,})/\1 |/' file.txt
```